# Modify color parameter in matplotlib with multi-index dataframe

Tags: python, dataframe, matplotlib, multi-index, line-plot

I am trying to modify a plot I have on a multi-index Pandas dataframe. Here is a sample of the dataframe:

```py
cluster    PredictionDate
FGCI 1.5   2022-04-11         0.778682
           2022-04-11         1.686295
           2022-05-10         1.689775
           2022-05-10         0.780289
           2022-06-09         0.781591
           2022-06-09         1.692596
FGCI 2.0   2022-04-11         1.176237
           2022-04-11         2.592334
           2022-04-11         2.071005
           2022-04-11         6.745330
           2022-04-11         1.089879
           2022-05-10         6.746528
           2022-05-10         1.176446
           2022-05-10         2.071373
           2022-05-10         2.592795
           2022-05-10         1.090073
           2022-06-09         2.071265
           2022-06-09         2.592660
           2022-06-09         6.746177
           2022-06-09         1.176384
           2022-06-09         1.090016
Name: weighted_MAPE_contrib, dtype: float64
```

And the code to build my plot:

```py
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for date, new_df in new_merged.groupby(level = 0):
    ax.plot(new_df.index.get_level_values('cluster').values,
            new_df['weighted_MAPE_contrib'],
            linestyle = '-',
            linewidth = 5)
    set_size(12,10)
    ax.set_ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error')
    ax.set_title('Weighted MAPE on Cluster Level for Grouped Vintages')
    locs, labels = plt.xticks(); plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)
    
plt.show()
```

[image: plot]

The plot looks good, but I would like to add a layer of specificity to the plot that would split each cluster's bars up by the `PredictionDate` index and color it in according to that date. Also, since there are multiple instances of each date for each cluster, I would just want to take the average of the `weighted_MAPE_contrib` for each date within each cluster and use that as the basis for the coloring. I've tried adding the following modifications to my code:

```py
from matplotlib import cm, colors

my_cmap = cm.viridis
for key, group, in new_merged.groupby(level = 1):
    my_norm = colors.Normalize(vmin=new_merged.index.get_level_values("PredictionDate").values.min(), vmax=new_merged.index.get_level_values("PredictionDate").values.max())
    
fig, ax = plt.subplots()

for date, new_df in new_merged.groupby(level = 0):
    ax.plot(new_df.index.get_level_values('cluster').values,
            new_df['weighted_MAPE_contrib'],
            color= my_cmap(my_norm(new_df.index.get_level_values('PredictionDate').values[date])),
            linestyle = '-',
            linewidth = 5)
    set_size(10,8)
    ax.set_ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error')
    ax.set_title('Weighted MAPE on Cluster Level for Grouped Vintages')
    locs, labels = plt.xticks(); plt.setp(labels, rotation=90)

plt.show()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
Input In [636], in <cell line: 14>()
     12 fig, ax = plt.subplots()
     14 for date, new_df in new_merged.groupby(level = 0):
     15     ax.plot(new_df.index.get_level_values('cluster').values,
     16             new_df['weighted_MAPE_contrib'],
---> 17             color= my_cmap(my_norm(new_df.index.get_level_values('PredictionDate').values[date]))
     18             linestyle = '-',
     19             linewidth = 5)
     20     set_size(10,8)
     21     ax.set_ylabel('Mean Absolute Percentage Error')

IndexError: only integers, slices (`:`), ellipsis (`...`), numpy.newaxis (`None`) and integer or boolean arrays are valid indices
```

But that gave the above error.